# Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed. Installation failed due to:

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to run my app on Android Studio 3.5. It throws an error while installing the app on the phone.

Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Installation failed due to: ''cmd package install-create -r -t --full -S 2164012' returns error 'Unknown failure: cmd: Failure calling service package: Failed transaction (2147483646)''
Retry

[image]

Comment: Are you running it on a HUAWEI device? I'm reading `nova 3` on the screenshot provided, I added a solution for Huawei device too please check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Close emulator
2. Wipe data in AVD Manager for a particular emulator.

Answer (score 2):

Since there can be multiple reasons why it occurred, please try the following - one should work:

1. Execute Build > Clean project. Then, again Build > Rebuild Project.
2. If still the error persists, Build > Make Project
3. Check if Instant Run is enabled on the Android Studio. If so, disable it by navigating to:
   `Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run`
4. Check if the phone storage is running low. If not, uninstall the previously installed app, run `adb uninstall <package_name>` command from the terminal to ensure uninstalling & try installing again
5. Check if USB Debugging is enabled in Developer options, if not - enable it.
6. For Huawei devices, after executing Clean Project, navigate to `Phone Manager > Cleanup and Optimize` - it also worked for me on 2 Huawei devices
7. For Xiaomi phones, turning Off MIUI optimization has always worked for me for all Xiaomi devices. Go to Settings, find Developer Options and tap on Turn Off MIUI optimization

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I was getting this error when I had `emulator-5554 (minSdk(API28))` selected as the deployment target, but it went away when I changed that to `Pixel_3a_API_30_x86`.